# Is the order of 1st ionization energies and order of the work function between some metals the same?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I understand that the ionization energy and  the work function are two different terms both used in different contexts. But as a highschooler, I have learnt more about comparing 1st ioniztion energies of elements than their work functions. Can those methods of comparison be applied to the work function as well. Currently, I don't see a reason why they should not work. Also, looking at some data about work functions it also seems to follow the same order as 1st ioniztion energies. For example, the ionization energies as well as the work funcitons of Li, Na, K are in the order - Li > Na > K. Will this be neccessarily the same and if no, how good of a guess can one make for determining the order of work functions using this assumption?

Comment: No, it's not true in general. Also work function isn't a constant.

Comment: The *1st ionization energies of elements* is measuring the energy needed to remove an electron from an "isolated" atom. The *work function* is measuring the energy needed to remove an electron from a bulk solid. In bulk metals the orbitals combine to create a "conduction band" of very loosely bound electrons. So you don't have "isolated" atoms anymore. Conversely in an bulk ionic solid like sodium chloride you have essentially sodium cations and chloride anions, not sodium and chlorine atoms. So don't expect excellent correlation between the first ionization potential and the work function.